# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 – Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, sql-server

Before I get redirected, I think this is a newer issue because I am using a setup that is different than others.

Not duplicate because that did not work/help because the instructions were unclear/vague.

So I have this running fine.. I think.. (SQL Server Configuration Manager).
I am not prompted here, but only when I open my application.

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

and I successfully linked it here (SQL Server Management Studio)

[image: SQL Server Management Studio]

Then in Visual Studios 2015 I go here. 
[image: Visual Studios]

And here is some of the code (which works and this runs)

```
  txtUsername.Text == "" || txt_Password.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide a Username and Password");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                //Create SqlConnection
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tabl_login where UserName=@username and Password=@password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_Password.Text);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapt.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
                if (count == 1)
                {


                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");

                    Form1 objFrmMain = new Form1();
                    this.Hide();
                    objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

But the problem is! This only works locally! :(. I want it run for others as well. Here is what happens on the VM and the issue. Please help!

[image]

Comment: So then add VS<version> to your post

Comment: Changed and it is 2015.